# Occurrence problem for commutator subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, word-problem

The occurrence problem asks if, given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, there exists an algorithm to decide whether $x\in G$ belongs to $H$.

Let $G$ be a group that has solvable word problem.

1. Is the occurrence problem solvable for $H=[G,G]$? In other words,
   Is there an algorithm to decide for any $x\in G$ whether $x$ belongs to $[G,G]$?

A slightly more general question:

2. Is there an algorithm to decide whether $x \in G$ belongs to the $k$-derived subgroup (recall that the $k$-derived subgroup $G_k$ is defined recursively as $G_1= [G,G]$, $G_k=[G_{k-1},G_{k-1}]$).

Also, any reference to these topics is welcome.

**Edit:** many replies pointed me out that the question for the cases $k=1,2$ is true even without assuming that $G$ has solvable word problem. I am still interested in the general case (question 2).

Comment: 1) Yes (assuming $G$ is meant to be finitely generated): more generally if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H$ has solvable word problem then there's an algorithm, which is precisely the one solving the word problem in $H$. This applies to the derived subgroup, and also to the second derived subgroup. I don't know then, since there are f.g. solvable groups with non-solvable word problem.

Comment: Thank you @YCor for your reply. I still looking for the case when $H$ is de $k$-derived subgroup. I don't have a good reference to look for it, so any book or paper with this concrete topic is welcome.

Comment: By the way the usual terminology is "membership problem".

Comment: @YCor In the West, yes, but many Russian authors still use “occurrence problem” and historically it is this terminology which is always used there.

Comment: Note that the hypothesis that $G$ has solvable word problem is *not* needed for question 1 -- all that's needed is the (uniform) word problem in the abelianisation $G/[G,G]$, which is a finitely generated abelian group.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Perhaps, but I have been working on algorithmic problems in group theory for 18 years and have never heard the terminology before. So I think it's fair to say that it remains very unusual in English-language mathematical parlance. And note that there are *many* Russian mathematicians working in the Western mathematical community on algorithmic problems in group theory.

Comment: @HJRW, you probably have cited the famous paper  K.A. Mihailova, The occurrence problem for direct products of groups, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 119 (1958) 1103–1105 showing the generalized word problem is undecidable for a direct product of free groups :) but I think the terminology has not been commonly used in English for quite some time. Here is a sort of exception https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-101-03/S0002-9939-1987-0908639-5/S0002-9939-1987-0908639-5.pdf but not very recent

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: You're right, I have cited that paper, and so I suppose I have brushed up against the terminology. Nevertheless, I wasn't aware of it, and didn't know what it meant.

Comment: @HJRW, no worries. That's where I learned the term but probably few people read the original paper where that terminology is used

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Anyway, I think that it is more specific than the membership/occurrence problem. As far as my knowledge, the membership/occurrence problem deals with finitely generated subgroups (arbitrary, given by generator as part of the input) and here the subgroup is fixed. I don't know if I should modify the name of the post or clarify this in any form. I am still interested in the answer. Regards!